# Spring boot WireMock junit5 not mocking an external call

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, wiremock

My `FristService` is internally calling a `SecondService` through `feign client`, and I am trying to write a test for `FirstService` and want to mock the call to the second service.

It seems like `wiremock` is unable to intercept and respond with the mock results but throws the following exception (as it's not mocking)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: second-service
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:90)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
```

Here is the Test code

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {WireMockInitializer.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestFirstController {

    @Autowired
    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Inject
    public MockMvc mockMvc;

    @LocalServerPort
    private Integer port;

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        this.wireMockServer.resetAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
        this.wireMockServer.stubFor(
                WireMock.get(urlPathMatching("/second-controller/1"))
                        .willReturn(aResponse()
                                .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                                .withBody("[{\"id\":1,\"message\":\"Child title 1\"}]"))
        );

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.request(HttpMethod.GET, "/first-controller/1"))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

here is my business method that first fetches record from the database and then makes a call to the second service

```
@Override
public First getFirst(Integer id) {
    First first = map(respository.findById(id));
    
    //feign-client call
    List<Second> seconds = client.getSeconds(id);
    first.setChild(seconds);

    return first;
}
```

and here is my feign client and I am not changing anything about it in test mode

```
@FeignClient("service-2")
public interface SecondApi {
    @GetMapping({"/second-controller/{id}"})
    SomeData getData(@PathVariable("id") Integer id);
}
```

Comment: I usually write mock realisation of feign client interface and make it @Primary in tests, it's very convenient way for me.

Comment: could you please elaborate more?

Comment: can you show the relevant parts of your FeignClient where you override the URL to point to the local WireMock URL during tests?

Comment: @rieckpil it could be the answer I am looking for, what my understanding is when you use `wire mock` you don't have to mock anything else hence I have not changed anything for feign-client in the test mode. I will add code of feign client as well

Comment: You somewhere have to adjust the base URL of your HTTP clients to not point to e.g. www.supercompany.com/api/products, but http://localhost:8080/api/products